# rails - 2 models with many-to-many relationships, passing ids and new objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, simple-form-for

My app has 2 many-to-many models:

- A kid can own many toys.
- A toy can be owned by many kids.
- An ownership table joins the kid and toy tables.

On the profile of each kid, I have a button to create a new toy via a form.
I want to create a new toy + my form to automatically pick-up the id of the kid currently using the app, so I can create a new line in the ownership table, which takes the kid_id and the toy_id.

I am not sure in which controller this should all happen, what routes to associate to this, and what to pass to simple_form_for.
I’ve looked a bit everywhere and the only answers I seem to find (probably because I don’t know what to ask google) asks the user to pick the toy amongst a collection of already existing toys. But in my case I need the toy to be created on the spot.

Comment: Maybe this sounds non-railsy, but in this case you may consider a OwnershipController of sorts which has actions/routes that can accept a kid_id and a toy_id, and perform the logic. This controller's responsibilities would be things related to associating, dis-associating, adding toys for a particular kid.

Comment: I was thinking of that, but where would I create the new toy then? Should it be in that OwnershipController too, or should it be in the ToyController? If it's in the ToyController, can I pass from the Create action in the ToyController directly to the Create action of the OwnershipController, while also passing the ids of everything? (I'll investigate today)

Comment: @mmcrae this question is a poor fit over there - too broad. Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with (you even got the site name wrong)

Comment: @gnat it changed to software engineering I guess. Ya got me